# Implement Kullback-Leibler as loss function for arbitrary distributions

Tags: tensorflow, probability, loss-function, gradient-descent

I had already implemented  an optimization (gradient descent) algorithm by using the Tensorflow-probability built-in KL-Divergence as a loss function. Theoretically it worked well, but then I found out that the list of registered distributions, which you are able to compare in the KL-Divergence, is quite limited. I tried to minimize the KL-Divergence of a Gaussian Mixture Model (as the true distribution) and a Normal Distribution (optimize Mean and Std, such that KL-Divergence becomes minimal), which was not possible.

So I tried to implement my own approach, which did not work:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import tensorflow as tf
```

The idea I had was to create densities of the needed distributions via scipy.stats (lets say Normal distributions) and transform the density-variables to Tensors:

```
x = np.arange(-10,10,0.001)
mu_train = tf.Variable(2.0)
p_pdf = norm.pdf(x, 0, 1)
q_pdf = norm.pdf(x, mu_train,1)

p = tf.convert_to_tensor(p_pdf)
q = tf.convert_to_tensor(q_pdf, dtype=tf.float64)
```

Now I defined the KL-Divergence as a function that only depends on q.

```
def kl_loss(q):
    return tf.reduce_sum(
        tf.where(p == 0, tf.zeros(p.shape, tf.float64), p * tf.math.log(p / q))
    )
```

Then I calculated the gradient of kl_loss with respect to mu_train, but the output I get from this a "None".

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(mu_train)
    loss = kl_loss(q)

d_loss_d_mu = tape.gradient(loss, mu_train)
print(d_loss_d_mu)
```

Now that I have thought about it.. to get a "None" as output makes sense to me, since kl_loss(q) is a function that does only depend on the values "q(x)", that are generated by the density q, but it does not depend on mu_train directly, since this is just a parameter of the Normal Distribution but the input for the kl_loss is an array/tensor of values of the normal distribution..

Does anyone know how I can find a workaround for this or does anyone else have a completely different solution to get the KL-Divergence as a loss function with arbitrary distributions, such that I can compute gradients with respect to parameters and run a GradientDescent Minimizer.